# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null, react native to backend drf with conditional form input

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, react-native, django-rest-framework

Using formdata to post to backend api, working with drf and react native, though if i take an image or snap an image it has no issue but my forms are conditional input, based on some condition image uploading is not required, i can't really say where exactly and have giving several condition to bypass this but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null, search but couldn't find this particular one for my answer any help with be deeply appreaciated.
also i have tested my backend well not issues whatsoever i believe this is frontend thing

serializer.py

```
bidderOneCac = serializers.FileField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False, allow_null=True, required=False)
```

react-native-code

```
const bidderOneImageUri = "file:///" + bidderonecac.split("file:/").join("");

formdata.append("bidderOneCac", {uri: bidderOneImageUri, type: mime.getType(bidderOneImageUri), name: bidderOneImageUri.split("/").pop()})
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null


 if(bidderonecac){
    var bidderOneImageUri = "file:///" + 
  bidderonecac?.split("file:/").join("")
  }else{
    var bidderOneImageUri = ""
  }
```

step to reproduce
django rest
react-native expo-image
mime

Comment: its good practice to check  `bidderonecac` might be null or undefined, performing operations like split, it's a good practice to check if the variable is not null or undefined

Comment: @Tanveer, definitely it would be null, it is base on conditional form selection that is where am getting the error, if you have better option of capturing this error help and drop it here appreciate your response

Comment: `serializer.py` file contains python code?

Comment: @Tanveer yes please i have updated the code, but it seems to be giving another error Network request failed, please note that i have my router ip configured as the main access point interface it is working for others but this particular image upload its giving issues without it,

Comment: are you familiar with java script and python language?

Comment: of course good at it but this is insane, i uses the expo for build... i will try work around it but if you do have any solution kindly drop it by appreciate you @Tanveer

Comment: @Tanveer okay i was able to debug the code commenting out the formdata that has to do with the image... so i was able to come to conclusion that the type for null value not detected making it hard to figure it out.